# pandas python drop columns

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I used this code to drop 4 columns from my dataframe.

```
HRdfMerged.drop(['Over18', 'StandardHours', 'MaritalStatus', 'RelationshipSatisfaction'], axis = 1)
```

When I run `list(HRdfMerged)` after dropping, those columns are still showing in my dataframe. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to reassign.  `HRdfMerged = HRdfMerged.drop.....` drop is not an inplace operation.  Or you can add a parameter `inplace=True` and not reassign.

Comment: Yes you are missing ```inplace=True```